# Return non-matching words from a dataframe column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe where I save customer names in 2 columns. I need to omit the common words from both columns and return the non-matching word.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

u_cols = ['page_id','web_id']
audit_trail = StringIO('''
shantanu prabhakar oak | santanu prabhakar oak
amar atmaram patil | amar atmaram patel 
''')

df11 = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep="|", names = u_cols  )
```

Expected results:

```
santanu
patel
```

What I have tried:

```
set(df11['page_id']) - set(df11['web_id'])

{'amar atmaram patil ', 'shantanu prabhakar oak '}
```

---

update:

It will be great if a dictionary is returned with corrections:

{'shantanu': 'santanu', 'patil': 'patel'}

I did not ask it before because I thought it was not possible within pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [5128]: df
Out[5128]:
                  page_id                 web_id
0  shantanu prabhakar oak  santanu prabhakar oak
1      amar atmaram patil     amar atmaram patel

In [5129]: df.apply(lambda x: set(x.web_id.split()) - set(x.page_id.split()), axis=1)
Out[5129]:
0    {santanu}
1      {patel}
dtype: object
```

Update

```
In [5134]: df.apply(lambda x: {b:a for a, b in zip(x.web_id.split(), x.page_id.split()) 
                               if a!=b}, axis=1)
Out[5134]:
0    {u'shantanu': u'santanu'}
1         {u'patil': u'patel'}
dtype: object
```

Or flat dict

```
In [5141]: vals = df.apply(lambda x: {b:a for a, b in zip(x.web_id.split(),
                                                          x.page_id.split())
                                      if a!=b}, axis=1)

In [5142]: {k:v for d in vals.values for k, v in d.items()}
Out[5142]: {'patil': 'patel', 'shantanu': 'santanu'}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Is it possible to return a dict? {'shantanu': 'santanu', 'patil': 'patel'} In other words, can I compare first, second and third word from both columns? There will always be 3 words.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pd.DataFrame.applymap` and `pd.DataFrame.diff`

```
df11.applymap(lambda x: set(x.split())).diff(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]

0    {santanu}
1      {patel}
Name: web_id, dtype: object
```

---

Or, create a space separated string

```
df11.applymap(lambda x: set(x.split())).diff(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].apply(' '.join)

0    santanu
1      patel
Name: web_id, dtype: object
```